# how to install libhdf5-dev? (without yum, rpm nor apt-get)

Tags: python, linux, installation, hdf5

I want to use h5py which needs libhdf5-dev to be installed. I installed hdf5 from the source, and thought that any options with compiling that one would offer me the developer headers, but doesn't look like it.

Anyone know how I can do this? Is there some other source i need to download? (I cant find any though)

I am on amazon linux, yum search libhdf5-dev doesn't give me any result and I cant use rpm nor apt-get there, hence I wanted to compile it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the issue is, that you didn't find the h5py's os level development lib. It is because you have been looking/searching with the wrong package name - the one you're trying is for Ubuntu, for CentOS it's `hdf5-devel`.

For **CentOS**

```
sudo yum -y install hdf5-devel
```

For **Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
```

**Note**: above command will install hdf5 development lib version `1.8.12`

---

Just recently I have installed `h5py` - with no hassle, the package versions I have installed:

```
numpy==1.11.2
h5py==2.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use pip?

```
pip install h5py
```

Comment: it gives me the `#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"`error which as far as I can tell is due to missing libhdf5-dev

Answer (score 0):

If you've built hdf5 library to a non-standard directory that is not included in your `PATH`, than you have basically two options. Either add this directory to you `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or you can specify these paths to `pip`. Something like this works:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I<path_to_direcotry_with_headers>" --global-option="-L<path_to_director_with_lib>" h5py
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Centos 8,** I got the below warning message :

> *Warning: Couldn't find any HDF5 C++ libraries. Disabling HDF5 support.*

and I solved it using the command :

> *sudo yum -y install hdf5-devel*